# SQL Insert fails via ADO.Net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2, .net-4.0, ado.net

I sent an INSERT statement to SQL Server 2008 R2 via:

```
Function ExecuteSQL(ByVal SQL As String, Optional ByVal UserConnectString As String = "", Optional ByVal MsgSuppress As Boolean = False) As Integer
    Dim cmd As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 'text commands only'
    Dim sConStr As String = UserConnectString
    If sConStr.Length = 0 Then sConStr = g.OISConnectString
    Dim i As Integer
    Try
        Using con As New SqlConnection(sConStr)
            con.Open()
            cmd.CommandText = SQL
            cmd.Connection = con
            i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Return i
            con.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        If Not MsgSuppress Then
            ExpLog.LogMsgBox(ex, "Unexpected error:" & vbCrLf & ex.Message & vbCrLf & SQL & vbCrLf & "Notify Programmers", , , "SQL: " & SQL)
        End If
        Return -1 'count'
    End Try
End Function
```

The SQL:

```
INSERT INTO MAF01_CA
SELECT TransId, TransDateStamp, LocalTransDateStamp, L2GMerchantCode, PayMethodCode, TotTransAmt, TotFeeAmt, TotMerchantAmt, AcctNbrLast5, AcctNbrData, UserPart1, UserPart2, UserPart3, UserPart4, UserPart5, UserPart6, AcctHolderName, BillingAddress, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingZip, BillingEmail, BillingPhone, AuthCode, LineItem, LineItemUserPart1, LineItemUserPart2, LineItemUserPart3, MerchantAmt, AcctNbrPrefix, AcctNbr, Clerk, Terminal, UserDefinedConstant, IsRefund, BatchOutId, BatchStatusCode, SettleMerchantCode, BatchDate, BatchTotAmt, BatchTransCnt, BatchAdjustAmt, BatchAdjustCnt, OrigTransID, Status, Comment, Last_Update_Date, TransIDEx
FROM   MAF01
WHERE  (TransId LIKE '3653511561%')
```

The SQL statement fails on `i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` with `Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type.` when sent via ADO.Net SqlClient. But works just fine in SQL Server Management Studio Query tool.

What might be causing this error?

Please - no comments on injection issues.

---

From table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MAF01_CA](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TransId] [bigint] NULL,
    [TransDateStamp] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [LocalTransDateStamp] [smalldatetime] NULL,
...
    [BatchDate] [smalldatetime] NULL,
...
    [Last_Update_Date] [smalldatetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MAF01_CA_Last_Update_Date]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
```

To Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MAF01](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TransId] [bigint] NULL,
    [TransDateStamp] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [LocalTransDateStamp] [smalldatetime] NULL,
...
    [BatchDate] [smalldatetime] NULL,
...
    [Last_Update_Date] [smalldatetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MAF01_Last_Update_Date]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
```

Comment: This is a data issue. You are inserting into a smalldatetime field (in MAF01_CA) from a string field in MAF01 which doesn't hold a valid date or is not in the correct date format.

Comment: That would seem logical however the data isn't on the client. The SQL SELECTs from one DB..Table and INSERTs to another DB.Table on the server. ADO.Net never has access to the data. A possible error would be the table designs doesn't match but that doesn't appear to be the case. I've added the DDL for all the date fields to the OP. All of the smalldatetime fields seem to be populated properly in the source record. Myguess is there is something else amiss and the `Conversion failed...` message is bogus.

Comment: The error message is coming directly from SQL Server and can be seen if you run the sql directly in Query Analyser. If you are certain the database table definitions are the same then I'd say the table column order doesn't match the select part.

Comment: I can run a copy of the INSERT SQL in SQL Manager and I don't get an error. The copy was extracted from the `.CommandText` after it was set in the code. My `ExecuteSQL()` is used in many places and works fine - something very dumb with my debugging or a very strange bug. A real puzzle that identical (hopefully) SQL would work in one case and not work the another.

Comment: Sounds strange. Only thing I can suggest is removing a few columns at a time to pinpoint the problematic one.

Answer (score 0):

I fully defined the fields to update and it worked from ADO.Net.

```
INSERT INTO table2
(column_name(s))
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1;
```

I guess the strangeness is that the first pattern worked at all.

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1; -- fails via ADO.Net
```